# Code coverage for a try-catch block

Tags: unit-test

I was not able to cover few lines from my apex class below:

**Controller class:**

```
public with sharing class Customsave {
   public Contact contact {get;set;}
   private String RecordTypeId, RecordTypeName; 
      public customsave(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
      contact= (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
     }   
  public PageReference save() {
       try{
           upsert contact;
           // PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CustomSave?id=' + contact.Id + '&retUrl=' + contact.Id);
           PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contact.Id );
           pageRef.setRedirect(true);
           return pageref;
           }
           catch(Exception ex){
           ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
           }
           return null;
        }
   public PageReference dosavenew() {
       try{
           upsert contact;
           PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CustomSave');
          // PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contact.Id );
           pageRef.setRedirect(true);
           return pageref;
           }
           catch(Exception ex){
           ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }
            return null;
           }
         }
```

**Test Class:**

```
 static testMethod void validateCustomsaveControllertest() 
         {
       Contact c = new Contact();
       c.FirstName = 'FirstTest';
       c.LastName = 'LastTest';
       try{
       insert c;
       //if(Test.isRunningTest())
       //integer intTest =1/0;  
        } catch(DMLexception ex)// exception handling
            {
            system.assertEquals(ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage());
             }
       //call the apexpages stad controller
       Apexpages.Standardcontroller stdcon = new Apexpages.Standardcontroller(c);
       Customsave con = new customsave(stdcon);
       con.save();
       con.dosavenew();
       }
```

**Here are the lines not covered:**

```
catch(Exception ex){
    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
      }
    return null;
```

Comment: Which of the fields (firstName, lastName) are mandatory?

Comment: just LastName is Mandatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception block can be covered in beow way:

```
static testMethod void validateCustomsaveControllertest() 
         {
       Contact c = new Contact();
       c.FirstName = 'FirstTest';
       c.LastName = 'LastTest';
       try{
       insert c;
       //if(Test.isRunningTest())
       //integer intTest =1/0;  
        } catch(DMLexception ex)// exception handling
            {
            system.assertEquals(ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage());
             }
       //call the apexpages stad controller
       Apexpages.Standardcontroller stdcon = new Apexpages.Standardcontroller(c);
       Customsave con = new customsave(stdcon);
       con.save();
       con.dosavenew();
       Contact exceptionContact=new Contact();
       stdcon = new Apexpages.Standardcontroller(exceptionContact);
       con = new customsave(stdcon);
       con.save();
       con.dosavenew();
       System.assertEquals(con.contact.id,null);
       }
```

Assertion in the last checks that contact record is not inserted when lastname of contact is null.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple in that you need to create data that causes the exception to occur in a separate test method. In your case, doing something that would cause your DML to fail like not including an email address which is a required field on Contact.

Comment: DML is not failing but I don't get a good code coverage. I'm trying to assert using the ex.message but still not working

Comment: I like to set `OwnerId` to some `Profile`. It's more consistent independent of  `sObjectType`.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner You need a separate method. One for positive condition and another for negative condition where you get a DML exception.